# Adding new page in itextsharp will overlap with header

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I am using iTextSharp version 5.4.5.0.

I have a problem while adding new page using document.NewPage() method.

When I will use above method to add new page, the content of this new page will overlap with my header section. I have created my header table in `OnEndPage()` method of `PdfPageEventHelper` class.

Here is the code for my header in `OnEndPage` event:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
table.TotalWidth = document.PageSize.Width - document.LeftMargin - document.RightMargin;
PdfPTable headerTable = new PdfPTable(1) { TotalWidth = document.PageSize.Width };

PdfPCell cImage = new PdfPCell(ImageHeader, true);
cImage.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
cImage.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
cImage.FixedHeight = 45f;
cImage.PaddingTop = 0f;

headerTable.AddCell(cImage);

PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(headerTable) { Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER };
table.AddCell(cell);

table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, document.LeftMargin, document.Top, writer.DirectContent);   // Here the document.Top value is 45
```

And I have also assign margin top as 45 while creating document object as below:

```
MemoryStream workStream = new MemoryStream();
Document document = new Document(); 

PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, workStream);
document.SetMargins(30, 30, 45, 30);
```

Can anyone help me to not overlap document content with header table while adding new page ?

Thanks.

Comment: This is the exact same question as [Page Header overlaps with Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35449606/page-header-overlaps-with-table) and the answer can be found on the official iText site: [Why is my content overlapping with my footer?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/why-my-content-overlapping-my-footer) On the site, it's about the footer, not the header, but the answer is identical: you need to define a margin that leaves sufficient room for the header (or footer).

Comment: See also [Why does my header overlap with my content?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/why-does-my-header-overlap-my-content)

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, document.LeftMargin, document.Top, writer.DirectContent);
```

You claim `// Here the document.Top value is 45` but that is **not correct**!

You create your document like this:

```
Document document = new Document();
```

This means that the lower-left coordinate of your document is `(0, 0)` and the upper-right coordinate is `(595, 842)`.

Then you define margins for the document:

```
document.SetMargins(30, 30, 45, 30);
```

This means that:

- `Document.Left` = 0 + 30 = 30
- `Document.Right` = 595 - 30 = 565
- `Document.Top` = 842 - 45 = 797
- `Document.Bottom` = 0 + 30 = 30

So when you have this line:

```
table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, document.LeftMargin, document.Top, writer.DirectContent);
```

You actually have:

```
table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 30, 797, writer.DirectContent);
```

This is totally wrong because that makes your table overlap with whatever content you are adding inside the margins.

To solve this, you need to calculate the height of the table. See for instance the answer to the question [How to define the page size based on the content?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-define-page-size-based-content)

```
table.LockedWidth = true;
Float h = table.TotalHeight;
```

Now you can use `h` to define the top margin:

```
document.SetMargins(30, 30, 20 + h, 30);
```

And you can use `Document.Top` to define the `y` position of the table:

```
table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1,
    document.LeftMargin,
    document.Top + h + 10,
    writer.DirectContent);
```

With this code, the table will be added *inside* the margin, leaving 10 user units of white space under the top of the page and 10 user units of white space above the top margin.

Comment: @Herin what was wrong with this answer? Why didn't it get accepted?