# Page Header overlaps with Table

Tags: itext

In itext, I have a table in my pdf. When the table gets full for a page the entries continues on the next page but it overlaps with my pdf page header. How do I avoid that?

Comment: You might also want to read my answer to the *identical question* that was posted one hour before yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35449121/adding-new-page-in-itextsharp-will-overlap-with-header

Comment: this doesnt work even after changing the values of the margin...playing with the value of top margin  just shifts the header up/down and the table yet overlaps with the header

Comment: It is Math @AbhimanyuKatoch You know the Y coordinate of the upper border (`ury`), you know the height of the upper margin (`m`), you know the Y coordinate of the upper margin (`ury - m`). You know the height of the table (`h`). You know that `m` must be greater than `h` (otherwise you can't fit the table in the margin). The Math to calculate the Y position of the table is simple: `ury - m + h`. This works for me. If it doesn't work for you: don't say ["this doesn't work"](http://lowagie.com/doesntwork) but show what you've tried and *prove that it doesn't work*!

Comment: See also [Why does my header overlap with my content?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/why-does-my-header-overlap-my-content)

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the [TableHeader](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/page-events/page-events-headers-and-footers#1631-tableheader.java) example.

In this example, I create a document with some "Hello World" content:

```
public void createPdf(String filename) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    TableHeader.HeaderTable event = new TableHeader.HeaderTable();
    // step 1
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 36, 36, 20 + event.getTableHeight(), 36);
    // step 2
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
    writer.setPageEvent(event);
    // step 3
    document.open();
    // step 4
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));
    document.newPage();
    document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));
    document.newPage();
    document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));
    // step 5
    document.close();
}
```

As you can see, I also define a `TableHeader` event. I use this `event` as a page event, but I also need this event when I define the `Document`. I use the following value as top margin:

```
20 + event.getTableHeight()
```

What does this mean? Let's take a look at the implementation of this event:

```
public class HeaderTable extends PdfPageEventHelper {
    protected PdfPTable table;
    protected float tableHeight;
    public HeaderTable() {
        table = new PdfPTable(1);
        table.setTotalWidth(523);
        table.setLockedWidth(true);
        table.addCell("Header row 1");
        table.addCell("Header row 2");
        table.addCell("Header row 3");
        tableHeight = table.getTotalHeight();
    }

    public float getTableHeight() {
        return tableHeight;
    }

    public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1,
                document.left(),
                document.top() + ((document.topMargin() + tableHeight) / 2),
                writer.getDirectContent());
    }
}
```

When I create the event, a `PdfPTable` is constructed. I store this `table` as a member variable, along with the height of this table: `tableHeight`.

I use this `tableHeight` when I define the top margin, so that I am 100% sure that the table will fit the margin. I add an additional 20 user units because I don't want the table to stick to the top border of the page:

```
20 + event.getTableHeight()
```

When I add the table in the `onEndPage()` method, I use the following coordinates:

```
x = document.left()
y = document.top() + ((document.topMargin() + tableHeight) / 2),
```

The value of `document.top()` is the value of the top of the page minus the top margin. I add some extra space, more specifically the difference of the top margin and the table height divided by two, added to the table height:

```
tableHeight + ((document.topMargin() - tableHeight) / 2)
```

This formula can be simplified to:

```
((document.topMargin() + tableHeight) / 2)
```

As you can see, all of this is simple Math, the kind of Math you are taught in primary school.

The resulting PDF looks like this:

[image]

This proves that your allegation that "it doesn't work" is wrong. Please understand that it is not polite to say "it doesn't work" after people have explained in great detail how to do something. By showing that *it does work*, people reading this could interpret your allegation as a lie (and that is bad for your karma).